# Laravel Join : Selecting all matching rows

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

i am trying to fetch product attributes by product id as below

```
$data['product']=  Product::select(
    'products.*',
    'product_attributes.id as product_attribute_id',
    'product_attributes.name as product_attribute_name',
    'product_attributes.value as product_attribute_value'
)
    ->leftjoin('product_attributes','product_attributes.product_id','=','products.id')
    ->where('products.id','=',$request['id'])
    ->get();
```

Below is my structure for attributes table

[image]

Now what happens is when i try to fetch product  attributes it only returns my one of the attributes (first record in attributes table)

Can someone please help me how can i fetch all the attributes for any given `product_id`

**EDIT ::**

just noticed when i dump data it returns me 3 records (indexes) , each index has one attribute value and product data( product data is repeating ) and i have only three attribute entries so it gives me 3 indexes ,

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use relations.

define attributes relation in the **Product Model**.

```
public function attributes() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class)
}
```

So the query would be easy now. As

```
Product::with('attributes')->findOrFail($productId);
```

Important Docs,

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it will work for your case.

```
    $data['product']=  Product::find($request['id']);

    $data['product_attributes'] = ProductAttributes::where('product_id','=',$request['id'])
                      ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it gives same result , also if you please could check my edit to the post

Comment: join returns all rows with matchings. so if you use join then your result is alright.

Comment: check my updated answer please.